# How to fix display flex with percent width columns 1px gap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On specific width display flex columns with percent width leave one 1px gap 
http://prntscr.com/gyhatt

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
}

.g {
  padding: 30px;
}

.grid-33 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.grid-50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.grid-66 {
  width: 66.6666%;
}

.grid-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.white {
  background: #fff;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ffb401;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="g  white grid-66">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="g yellow grid-33">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Themezly/hgtfnLdb/)**

I have already tried setting the grid-33 at  33.3334% and it does not work plus it is not useful since I am working with a framework and cant "nudge" specific columns to fix an actual layout issue. I was hoping that flex box dimensions would be like display table where px are rounded up but seems like that is not the case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What web browser are you using? I see no gap in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Let me know if my answer were helpful and can be accepted and/or upvoted ... or it simply didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That issue is a bug (or rounding issue) that among other Chrome and Edge have, but not Firefox.

- https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2006-January/002684.html
- http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/
- https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

---

I found 2 workarounds, one where you add `justify-content: space-between;` to the flex container (still it appears that at some screen width's Chrome still has that 1px issue)

Stack snippet

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
}

.g {
  padding: 30px;
}

.grid-33 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.grid-50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.grid-66 {
  width: 66.6666%;
}

.grid-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.white {
  background: #fff;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ffb401;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="g  white grid-66">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="g yellow grid-33">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And the other is to use `flex: 1 1 0`/`flex: 2 2 0`, where the `flex-grow/flex-shrink` is 1 of 3 and 2 of 3, so they both grow and shrink equally.

*Note, is is important to use it like this, where its `flex-basis` is set to 0, or else the content will be taken into account before the available space will be distributed between the items.*

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
}

.g {
  padding: 30px;
}

.grid-33 {
  width: 33.3333%;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.grid-50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.grid-66 {
  width: 66.6666%;
  flex: 2 2 0;
}

.grid-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.white {
  background: #fff;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ffb401;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="g  white grid-66">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="g yellow grid-33">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first one , space-between just moves the bug in chrome http://prntscr.com/gyw8al as you mentioned , second one changes the width of the containers so one third is not one third anymore. But thnx for acknowledging that it is a rounding bug.

Comment: il accept your answer knowing that none of the suggested "fixes" work since it is a browser bug. Since I have a surrounding container I managed to stretch the right column with negative right margin of 1px. I guess all I needed is someone to confirm that it is an actual bug which you did.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can leave the `width` attribute and go with [**`flex-grow`**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp) it's an attribute of `flex`:

In your case, I tried using -

```
.grid-33 {
  flex-grow: 3;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 3;
}

.grid-66 {
  flex-grow: 7;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 7;
}
```

and in my view, it looks same if there is any change you can adjust it with `flex-grow` value.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
}

.g {
  padding: 30px;
}

.grid-33 {
  flex-grow: 3;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 3;
}

.grid-50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.grid-66 {
  flex-grow: 7;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 7;
}

.grid-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.white {
  background: #fff;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ffb401;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="g  white grid-66">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="g yellow grid-33">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hm , that fixes it but again , it is a framework that already has defined widths in percentage but il try .

Comment: @Benn if it has fixed `width` then in your custom style over-right it with `width: auto`(use `!important` if your custom code is over-right by the framework code)